# Java Signature Timings/Overhead

Tags: encryption, java, digital-signature

I'm trying to make use of Java signatures in a pretty time sensitive setting.

I've come across some interesting behavior when signing data of a few hundred bytes. I am reusing a generated key, but recreating the Signature object each time I sign. The first time the signing happens it takes from anywhere from 50-100ms depending on the machine being used. However, any subsequent times a signature is computed over new data (using the same key) the time is reduced down to 1-2ms. I'm using SHA512 with RSA so I expected it to be heavier.

Can anyone explain why this happens? A test class I am using is pasted below (which is using identical code to my target applictaion).

```
    import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        //Generate key pair
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair(999);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("KeyGen: " + (end - start));

        //Sign first piece of data
        byte[] data = { ** a few hundred bytes** };
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] digitalSignature = signData(data, keyPair.getPrivate());
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Sign: " + (end - start));
        boolean verified;

        byte[] data2 = {** a different few hundred bytes ** };

        //sign second piece of data
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        digitalSignature = signData(data2, keyPair.getPrivate());
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(" Second Sign: " + (end - start));

        //verify second signature
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        verified = verifySig(data2, keyPair.getPublic(), digitalSignature);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Verify: " + (end - start));
        System.out.println(verified);


    }

    public static byte[] signData(byte[] data, PrivateKey key) throws Exception {
        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
        signer.initSign(key);
        signer.update(data);
        return (signer.sign());
    }

    public static boolean verifySig(byte[] data, PublicKey key, byte[] sig) throws Exception {
        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
        signer.initVerify(key);
        signer.update(data);
        return (signer.verify(sig));

    }

    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair(long seed) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        SecureRandom rng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        rng.setSeed(seed);
        keyGenerator.initialize(1024, rng);

        return (keyGenerator.generateKeyPair());
    }

}
```

This results in the output (time in ms)

```
KeyGen: 81
Sign: 52
Second Sign: 2
Verify: 2
```

I put some benchmarks on each line of the sign method, and  it appears the overhead is purely from the sign action itself.

```
Create Sig Obj: 1
Init sign: 1
update: 0
Sign: 49
Create Sig Obj: 1
Init sign: 0
update: 0
 Second Sign: 2
```

Any insight would be much appreciated

Comment: You will probably find better results on stackoverflow given that its more of a programming problem. That said, it looks like your test setup relies on restarting the app to see the Sign method take so long. It's very likely doing first time loads of some resource(s). You're not going to be able to get around this initial load, short of digging in and rewriting the actual bit of framework code that takes so long.

Comment: In particular the first time you call something in a JVM it demand-loads the underlying and supporting classes (probably over a hundred for the operations you're doing here) and that is relatively slow and costly. Also if you execute something a large number of times in one JVM -- where 'large' varies widely with Java version, environment, and proverbial 'phase of the moon' -- JIT compiling kicks in and tries to make it much faster. Most applications care about steady-state operation and not startup, but if you care about startup don't use Java.

Comment: Thanks both. The setting I am using it in will potentially be doing a large (10s or maybe even 100s) of sign operations a second and will be kept up for long periods so the startup time is not really important. I suspected it was loading operations causing it, but I assumed most of the class loading would have been during Signature object creation and initialisation,  not the sign itself.

Comment: To execute a performance test it is necessary to execute the operations multiple times to eliminate the effects of initialization. If you create a loop and calculate average times, you will probably see that the key generation time is much longer than the signature and verification time